# Recursion and merge sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Never had a good relationship with recursion. So I need to understand what's going on in those scripts. first of all, we have a "merge script":

```
def merge(list_1, list_2):
    result = list()

    while len(list_1) > 0 and len(list_2) > 0:
        list_1_item = list_1[0]
        list_2_item = list_2[0]

        if list_1_item <= list_2_item:
            result.append(list_1_item)
            list_1.remove(list_1_item)
        else:
            result.append(list_2_item)
            list_2.remove(list_2_item)
    result.extend(list_1)
    result.extend(list_2)

    return result
```

that script simply merges two lists in an ordered way, then we have the mergesort algorithm:

```
def mergesort(input_list):

    if len(input_list) <= 1:
        return input_list
    else:
        input_list_len = len(input_list)
        mid = input_list_len // 2

        left = mergesort(input_list[0:mid])
        #print(left)
        right = mergesort(input_list[mid:input_list_len])
        #print(right)


        return merge(left, right)
```

Now I'm a bit lost, i tried to figured out what's going on on a piece of paper:

In the mergesort function, the final statement `(return merge(left,right))`how many times is executed?

if I print the left and right value, I get this as output:

```
[1]
[23]
[1, 23]
[3]
[56]
[8]
[8, 56]
[3, 8, 56]
```

now this suggests to me that: for the first execution we have (give `mergesort([1,23,3,56,8])`)

```
left = mergesort([1,23])
right = mergesort([3,56,8])
```

now we concentrate to left, the mergesort function run and we have:

```
left = mergesort([1])
right = mergesort([23])
```

and in the sametime we have:

```
left = mergesort([3])
right = mergesort([56,8])
```

now the function should concentrate on list [56,8] and give us:

```
left = mergesort([56])
right = mergesort([8])
```

is it correct? My question is: if the function split the input list until we have list of one single item, shouldn't return that list, like the if block states? and when the final merge function start to working and what is his first input?
i know I'm bit confused..
many thanks

Comment: So the merge sort algorithm says basically "to sort an array, split it in half, sort each part, then merge it together". And a one-element array is already sorted by default. 1. Your analysis of what happens with `left` and `right` is correct. 2. `mergesort([3])` does return `[3]`; what makes you think it doesn't? 3. The first `merge` will happen after the first time both `left` and `right` are calculated, which will be `merge([1], [23])`, resulting in `[1, 23]`.

Comment: You answered your own question. left = mergesort([1,23]) right = mergesort([3,56,8]) and the final merge is next. So if you want to know what gets passed to the final merge, it is that left and that right. Thus you were correct all along. (There is a performance bug, but not really relevant to the question).

Comment: @KennyOstrom hi, can you explain the bugs you addressed? I'm interested thanks!

Comment: If you recall from the time complexity of merge sort, the merge operation was assumed to be O(n). However, within a loop which you would expect to have about n iterations, you are using remove on your sublists, which is itself O(n) https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity making your merge O(n**2). Use a simple index like the example code so you don't do extra work maintaining your temporary sublists.